# TS-Jest fails to recognize webpack Define plugin variables

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to run (TS)-Jest in my application that contains a few global variables that get injected at build time by Webpack (with Define Plugin)

For example:

```js
console.log(`Current build: ${__BUILD_VERSION}`)
```

The variable __BUILD_VERSION is not defined anywhere in the code so TS complains about it.

Here's the output when attempting to run Jest:

```
src/.../.../file.ts - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__BUILD_VERSION'.
```

I have tried defining them as Jest "globals" with no luck. Apparently is a Typescript error so maybe i should try something in `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this variables when running `jest` then set `globals` flag flag in your `jest.config` (or in `package.json` if you using it for config):

```js
"globals": {
  "__BUILD_VERSION": 123,
  "YOUR_OTHER_VARIABLE": 'foo'
}
```

If you need to fix Typescript then you need to declare that variable somewhere, for example create `globals.d.ts` file and declare it there:

```
declare const __BUILD_VERSION: string;
```

Comment: As i said. I did but it does not work.
I have tried both in package.json and in jest.config.
As you can see is a Typescript error. Jest doesn't even get to the point of parsing these global variables

Comment: I've edited my answer to include both cases. It is unclear in your question what do you want, fix jest or typescript?